# Renaming a .Zip entry using only C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

So what I'm trying to do right now is opening a .Zip file and renaming a file inside it (.NET 4.6.1). I don't think I'm allowed to use third-party libraries since this is a very simple operation (or so I thought, because I couldn't find any MSDN function to rename entries).

I found a couple of ways, but they are nasty. You can extract the file to disk and add it again with a different name, or you can also create a new entry with the new name in the zip, copy the file through a stream, and delete the original entry.

Is there any effective way to do this? I don't mind any ideas at this point. I know that with DotNetZip its only one line but I can't use a third part library.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `ZipArchive` in `System.IO.Compression`. Here is an example that adds a `.dat` extension to every entry in the specified zip file:

```
private static void RenameZipEntries(string file)
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        var entries = archive.Entries.ToArray();
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var newEntry = archive.CreateEntry(entry.Name + ".dat");
            using (var a = entry.Open())
            using (var b = newEntry.Open())
                a.CopyTo(b);
            entry.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "you can also create a new entry with the new name in the zip, copy the file through a stream, and delete the original entry" though =(.

Comment: @Damieh You can not add a new entry to the file without rewriting the hole file buddy. It might only be possible if the new name has the same length as the old name. And even then you would probably need to take apart the zip file yourself.

Comment: I don't want to add a new entry. Just rename it. So in order to rename the file I have to copy its entire contents? It wouldn't be a problem if the file I'm trying to rename wasn't like 900MB. Oh and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Damieh As I said before you can "easily" change names when the new name as exactly the same as the old one. Everything beyond that would require you to look into the specs of a zip file in more detail. It looks like an entry in a zip file is preceded by a 4 byte length indicator (little endian).

Comment: Where are you getting this info? I'd love a link or something!

Comment: @Damieh I just looked at the file itself. But after a quick Google search I got this [link](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). Look at chapter 4.3.6 ff.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Exactly what I needed